# Проблема с подписью apk файла

Tags: android, android-manifest

Пытаюсь сделать подписанный apk с помощью Build->Generate Signed APK... Но не получается. Причиной тому сия ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем ругается в манифесте, который генерируется при самом билде, то есть не в основном.

В основном манифесте же, конечно всё прописано, и прекрасно работает

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Не совсем понятна причина ошибки. Сталкивался кто?

Comment: ну вообще-то ругается что в ресурсах нет... Точно есть такой ресурс `@string/google_maps_key` и он в `values` а не в `values-XXX`. И кстати, а зачем писать `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` оно и так есть в `aar` которая используется обычно.

Comment: Да, именно в values, уже сто раз все проверил.. Если просто сбилдить проект, то все прекрасно работает.

Comment: да подпишите через консоль тогда :) я так понимаю clean тоже не помог.

Comment: clean/rebuld/reboot компа/танцы с бубнами/без бубнов никак не помогли=) через консоль еще не пробовал

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скорее всего `@string/google_maps_key"` сылается на каталог который в релиз не попадает, к примеру в каталоге `debug`... Добавьте ссылку на ресурс в каталог проекта `main` или `release`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот это интересно, сейчас попробую

Comment: Тысяча чертей! Это сработало! Спасибо=)

Comment: Я знал!!! я знал!!!! Не за что ;)